# How to print from a kiosk app on Ubuntu Core 18 to an attached usb printer?

Tags: printing, snap, ubuntu-core

I am new to Ubuntu Core and Snaps so please bare with me.

I believe I am missing a body of knowledge in understanding how snaps work and interact with one another. Have read up on snap Interfaces/Connections, plugs and slots and am not able to believe that printing from a snap is not possible.

**Some Background:**
On an Ubuntu Core 18 installed on an Intel NUC I am attempting to run a Kiosk using an electron based kiosk app (based on Ubuntu tutorial [Make a HTML5/Electron-based Kiosk Snap](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/electron-kiosk#0)).

The kiosk is performing well until I get to printing.

After ssh into the Ubuntu Core and from the user root (sudo su - root), am able to send text directly to a usb connected receipt thermal printer with success.

```
ls -la > /dev/usb/lp3
```

Installing [printing-stack-snap](https://snapcraft.io/printing-stack-snap) snap, I am able to pipe or print a text file to the cups printer as the Ubuntu One user used to install the Ubuntu Core 18 by using any one of the below command with success.

```
cat <text file> | printer-stack-snap.lp -d printer
printer-stack-snap.lp -d printer <text file>
```

From the app itself, using the node.js child process, am able to exec a shell command, but not able to invoke the printing-stack-snap.lp command. Recieving a exec error: /bin/sh: 1: printing-stack-snap.lp not found.

This probably has to do with how ubuntu core permissions work. What would be the use of using Ubuntu Core as a kiosk environment if one is unable to print a receipt for a sale?

Any guidance and assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This change https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/8329 which is currently in snapd in the edge channel, should help you to use the raw-usb interface in your snap to access /dev/usb/lpX directly ...